# Mysql Capacity with some Server specifications

Tags: mysql, web-server

I wonder how many capacity of Mysql.
Please tell me with details of some Server Specifications(OS,CPU,RAM...).

Thanks in advanced,
Rithy

Answer (score 2):

Wow -- this is an impossible question to answer. Other than using the ambiguous term "capacity", it's all really dependent on your dataset, schema and your usage patterns.

Having said that, most applications are bottlenecked by disk seeks (rather than being limited by the CPU).  If I had to sum up a starting point in one sentence, I'd say use InnoDB for all your tables and make sure your entire dataset (data plus indexes) fits in your InnoDB buffer pool (RAM).

Comment: Thank you, what if I need at least 10GB for each DB in the Database server? My server is Windows 2003 Server with 4GB RAM and my DB has MyISAM as default storage engine and data plus indexes, what should I do and check?

Comment: In my opinion, 4GB of RAM is likely not sufficient for a single 10GB database, let alone having more than one, regardless of your usage patterns. Plus the fact you're running it on Windows. Even if MyISAM is your default storage engine, you can change that / convert to InnoDB if your application would allow for it.